# Puppet: lookup and merge uniq hiera hashes

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a hiera construct that provides certificate names for the apache module that looks like this:

```
profiles::web_host::vhosts::params:
  'subdomain.domain.de'
    serverName: 'subomain.domain.de'
    certificateName: 'wildcard.domain.de'
  'subdomain2.domain.de'
    serverName: 'subomain2.domain.de'
    certificateName: 'wildcard.domain.de'
```

In my webserver profile there's a lookup for the params

```
$vhostParams = lookup("profiles::web_host::vhosts::params")
```

And then I'm looping over the params:

```
$vhostParams.each |$key, $vhOptions| { 
    if $vhOptions['certificateName'] {
       $certificateName = $vhOptions['certificateName']
    }
}
```

Here's the problem: As soon as you use a wildcard certificate (as intended) for multiple subdomains there's a duplicate definition for the variable $certificateName.

I experimented with .unique applied to the variable as well as during the lookup `$vhostParamsMerged1 = lookup('profiles::web_host::vhosts::params',Hash,'uniq',undef)` without much success.

I'd be glad if you can help.

Kind regards,
Thomas

Comment: Could you post your full code and the error message, please? I'm guessing you are using certificateName as the title of a resource, which is where the duplication becomes a problem, but that isn't clear from your question

Comment: Actually, it appears that your problem derives from iterating over a hash of size greater than 0. Therefore, after the very first iteration, your variable will be reassigned a value, which violates the immutability of Puppet variables, especially at the lambda scope. Could you please share the context of what you are attempting to achieve so we can provide guidance?

Comment: @MattSchuchard actually (and surprisingly) that code should work, without complaining about reassingment. Try this with puppet apply: `$hash = {
  'foo' => 1,
  'bar' => 2,
}

$hash.each | $key, $value | {
  $foo = $value
}
`

Comment: So yes, the problem is not multiple definition of a variable, but no, that is not surprising, because a lambda creates its own local scope: "Every lambda creates its own local scope which is anonymous, and contains variables which can not be accessed by qualified names from any other scope."  ([Puppet docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.10/lang_lambdas.html#behavior))

Comment: But that begs the question of what actually *is* problematic.  Nothing in the manifest code presented explains why it would be a problem for the certificate name to be non-unique.  Is it being used as a resource title?  We need a [mre] to be able to say anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for looking into this :)
I was ill for a while so sorry for my late feedback.
You're right I should've postet the whole profile but it contains some hostnames I dont want to go public.

I solved it by workaround.
The same certificate is now put into many files based on the vhost it is used by.

If anyone has a solution how to use the puppet function .each looping through hiera, create an array/hash and use only unique values - I'm still interested.

For everyone who has a similar problem:
Like always - you just have to make all your resources unique.

For my case the code now looks a like this (each time for ssl certificate and key):

```
      $vhostParams.each |$key, $vhOptions| { 
      [...]
      #
      # Certificate(s)
      #
      file { "Web Server vhost $defaultSslZone SSL Key for ${key}":
        # notifies the apache service to do a reload
        notify => Class['apache::service'],
      [...]
      apache::vhost { "${key}":
      ssl                  => true,
      ssl_cert             => "${cCERTS_BASE_DIR}/${sslZone}-${key}_cert.pem",
      ssl_key 
      }

         => "${cCERTS_BASE_DIR}/${sslZone}-${key}_key.pem",
```